# What does closed under convolution mean in Probability Theory?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, convolution

I understand what does it mean for a set to be closed under addition or multiplication, i.e. the sum/product of elements in a set, is still in a set.

Now, I am a little bit confuse when it says the distribution (stable distribution) is closed under convolution.

This is what I think it means, 
Let D be a family of stable distribution. For any $f, g \in D$, then $(f*g) \in D$ where $(f*g)$ is a convolution of $f$ and $g$, defined by $(f*g) = \int_{-inf}^{inf} f(\tau)g(t-\tau) d\tau $.

Comment: yes it is what it means. but you noticed that the random variable $Z = X+ Y$, (if $X,Y$ are independent) its pdf is $f_Z = f_X \ast f_Y$ ? hence in probability theory, a set of probability density functions is closed under convolution  means that the corresponding set of random variables is closed for the addition